# How to add items into two tables in the same express function (mysql)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm creating a cart for a virtual store, and when pressing "submit" button I need to insert the order into the "order" table and the items into the "orderitems" table.

I've been using express to insert things in only one table each function, but now I need to put both in the same... I'm trying to do it with promisses.

This is my html:

```html
<table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr scope="row">
                    <th scope="col">Product name</th>
                    <th scope="col">Price</th>
                    <th scope="col">Quantity</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr v-for="product in cart" v-bind:key="product.id" scope="row">
                    <td scope="col">{{product.name}}</td>
                    <td scope="col">{{product.price | currency}}</td>
                    <td scope="col"><input type="text" class="input-group-text" v-model="product.quantity"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3">Frete: {{fare | currency}}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3" class="highlighted">Total: {{total | currency}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <button class="btn btn-info" @click="registerTransaction()">Submit cart</button>
```

this is the function I call:

```
registerTransaction(){
            const date = new Date()
            const dateTime = {
                day: date.getUTCDate(),
                month: date.getUTCMonth(),
                year: date.getUTCFullYear(),
                hour: date.getUTCHours() - 3,
                minute: date.getUTCMinutes(),
                sec: date.getUTCSeconds()
            }
            const transaction = {
                date: new Date(`${dateTime.year}-${dateTime.month}-${dateTime.day}T${dateTime.hour}:${dateTime.minute}:${dateTime.sec}Z`)
            }
            transaction.userid = 1
            transaction.fare = parseFloat(this.fare)
            transaction.total = parseFloat(this.total)
            transaction.cart = this.cart


            axios.post(`${baseApiUrl}/checkout`, transaction)
                .then(() => this.$toasted.global.defaultSuccess())
                .catch(showError)
        }
```

and this is my backend for axios:

```
const save = (req, res) =>{
        const transaction = {...req.body}

        try{
            existsOrError(transaction.date, "Error: transaction date is invalid")
            existsOrError(transaction.userid, "Error in the user authentication")
            //existsOrError(transaction.fare, "Error in calculating the fare")
            existsOrError(transaction.total, "Error in the total value")
        }
        catch(msg){
            return res.status(400).send(msg)
        }

        app.db('orders')
            .insert(transaction)
            .then(console.log('feito!'))
            .then(saveProducts(transaction))
            .catch(err => res.status(500).send(err))



    }

    const saveProducts = (transaction) => {
        const orderId = app.db(`orders`).select(`idOrder`) .where({idClient: transaction.userid}).last()
        console.log('Done')
        for(let i = 0; i < transaction.cart.length; i++){
            quantity = app.db('products').select('quantity').where({id: transaction.cart[i].id}).first()
            quantity -= transaction.cart[i].quantity
            app.db('products').update(quantity).where({id: transaction.cart[i].id})
            const orderedProduct = {idOrder: parseInt(orderId), idProduct: parseInt(transaction.cart[i].id), quantity: parseInt(transaction.cart[i].quantity)}
            app.db('orderedproducts').insert(orderedProduct).then(console.log('produto inserido')).catch(err => res.status(500).send(err))
        }
        return
    }
```

I expected it to save first my order, call the saveProducts function to save the products in it, and return, but it's returning a error as if it's not allowed to do...

Comment: what is the error ?

Comment: it goes through all the code, doesn't change my registers in the database and returns "[object Object]" as error message

Comment: I found one of the problems! It was the datetime format, I just changed: date: new Date(${dateTime.year}-${dateTime.month}-${dateTime.day}T${dateTime.hour}:${dateTime.minute}:${dateTime.sec}Z) to: date: ${dateTime.year}-${dateTime.month}-${dateTime.day} ${dateTime.hour}:${dateTime.minute}:${dateTime.sec} but now I can't find a way to get the orderId from my database, if someone can help...

Comment: `app.db(`orders`).select(`idOrder`) .where({idClient: transaction.userid}).last()
        console.log('Done')` are those ORM methods or something ? If yes which ORM are you using and I think if it is an async call then you may need to call an await or if you are using promise then, it will have to add then callback.

Comment: I'm not using ORM methods... I'll try with async await and I post the results here :)

Comment: just curious to know the `select`, `where` and `last` methods that you have specified, where are they coming from ?

Comment: No result with async await... As I'm new to node, callback is a subject I didn't get entirely, so... can you clarify this suggestion you gave above for me?

Comment: Ohh, I see! hahaha It comes from knex a query buider for mysql, msql and posgresql =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went through the documentation and found the folllowing, which basically means that query methods has a promise interface meaning we can attach a `then` and catch method. It also means that we can use `async/await` on it.

```
knex.select('*')
  .from('users')
  .where({name: 'Tim'})
  .then(function(rows) {
    return knex.insert({user_id: rows[0].id, name: 'Test'}, 'id').into('accounts');
  })
  .then(function(id) {
    console.log('Inserted Account ' + id);
  })
  .catch(function(error) { console.error(error); });
```

For your code I have added `async/await`, if you like you can use `then` method.

```
const save = (req, res) => {
  const transaction = { ...req.body };

  try {
    existsOrError(transaction.date, "Error: transaction date is invalid");
    existsOrError(transaction.userid, "Error in the user authentication");
    //existsOrError(transaction.fare, "Error in calculating the fare")
    existsOrError(transaction.total, "Error in the total value");
  } catch (msg) {
    return res.status(400).send(msg);
  }

  try {
    let orderId = await app
      .db("orders")
      .insert(transaction);
    console.log('order inserted :' + orderId);

    await saveProducts(transaction);
    console.log("saved all the products");
  } catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
};

const saveProducts = async transaction => {
  const orderId = await app
    .db(`orders`)
    .select(`idOrder`)
    .where({ idClient: transaction.userid })
    .last();
  console.log("orderId : " + orderId);
  let quantity;
  for (let i = 0; i < transaction.cart.length; i++) {
    quantity = await app
      .db("products")
      .select("quantity")
      .where({ id: transaction.cart[i].id })
      .first();
    quantity -= transaction.cart[i].quantity;
    await app
      .db("products")
      .update(quantity)
      .where({ id: transaction.cart[i].id });
    const orderedProduct = {
      idOrder: parseInt(orderId),
      idProduct: parseInt(transaction.cart[i].id),
      quantity: parseInt(transaction.cart[i].quantity)
    };
    let insertedId = await app
      .db("orderedproducts")
      .insert(orderedProduct)
      .catch(err => res.status(500).send(err));
    console.log("inserted ordered product");
  }
  return;
};
```

> NOTE:  I have not executed the code so I can't guarantee that it will
>   work the way you want it to be, but I am sure this will give you an
>   idea how to move forward.